# android rxjava2 zip vararg parameter

Tags: android, kotlin, zip, rx-java2

I m now working on about the `rxjava2` in android kotlin . And try to write a function to zip multiple observable and observer. But it seems like some mistake. Can anyone help?
First , i try to write zip 2 observable and it works. but when I want to extend it to vararg , it fails.

```kotlin
fun <T> ApiSubscribeZip2(observable1: Observable<T>, observable2: Observable<T>, observer: Observer<List<T>>) {
    Observable.zip(observable1, observable2, BiFunction<T, T, List<T>> { t1: T, t2: T ->
        zipAdd(t1, t2)
    })
        ?.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())?.unsubscribeOn(Schedulers.io())?.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        ?.subscribe(observer as Observer<in List<T>>)
}

fun <T> ApiSubscribeZipN(vararg observable: Observable<T>?, observer: Observer<List<T>>) {
    Observable.zip(observable, Function<T, List<T>> { it ->
        zipAdd(it)

    })
}

private fun <T> zipAdd(vararg observableType: T): List<T> {
    val list = ArrayList<T>()
    for (ob in observableType) {
        list.add(ob)
    }
    return list
}
```

the apisubscribezipN   shows that None of the following function can be called with the arguments supplied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Observable.zipIterable` like this:

```kotlin
fun <T> ApiSubscribeZipN(vararg observable: Observable<T>?, observer: Observer<List<T>>) {
    Observable.zipIterable<T, List<T>>(observable.filterNotNull().toList(), { it.toList() as List<T>? }, false, 100)
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).unsubscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.io())
        .subscribe(observer)
}
```

Comment: it works!!!!! thanks but  is it possible to use zip only ?  but not zipiterable

Comment: I'm afraid no due to 'zipper' function. It cannot take variable number of parameters

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
import io.reactivex.Observable
import io.reactivex.functions.Function
import org.junit.Test

fun <T> apiSubscribeZipN(vararg observable: Observable<T>?): Observable<List<T>> {
    val filterNotNull = observable.filterNotNull()
    return Observable.zip(filterNotNull, Function { inArr ->
        inArr.map {
            it as T
        }
    })
}
```

Test

```
@Test
fun whatever() {
    val mergeWith1 = Observable.fromArray("test11", "test12").mergeWith(Observable.never())
    val mergeWith2 = Observable.fromArray("test21", "test22").mergeWith(Observable.never())

    apiSubscribeZipN(mergeWith1, mergeWith2)
        .test()
        .assertValues(listOf("test11", "test21"), listOf("test12", "test22"))
}
```